# Unable to set SDK path in android studio 3?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I installed android studio 3(v3.1.2.Build.173.4720617.x64) on windows 10.
It can not find SDK path and after some research on the internet i found that i should looking for a path like this on my computer:

```
C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Android\SDK
```

but this path was not on my machine and i created it by myself and copy a SDK in it(Android.SDK.26.1.1).

But android studio is unable to determine this path and when i want to set this path on SDK manager it shows this message:

```
 Target folder is neither empty nor does it point to an existing SDK installation.
```

this made me tired, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the location of your android SDK with the android studio to where you have your SDK installed. The path does not have to be in the format which you have stated. 
I have my SDK in another partition of my system and it works very fine.

Comment: I copied my SDK in another directory like c:\SDK and test it put it didn't work

Comment: Have you checked your user settings. You can reinstall the android studio.

Comment: where is the user settings?

Answer (score 0):

Have you paid attention that in that address `user1` should be your own user name? 
like in this address which my user name is `violet` :

```
C:\Users\violet\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

And after downloading sdk zipped file, then you should unzip it and next copy all files and folders to the sdk folder.